# css ignores "display: inline" on zoom

Tags: css

When I zoom, css ignores "display: inline"

### [image: problem]

### [problem2 http://screenshu.com/static/uploads/temporary/bc/r3/cf/ae0b2a.jpg](http://screenshu.com/static/uploads/temporary/bc/r3/cf/ae0b2a.jpg)

[problem3 http://screenshu.com/static/uploads/temporary/91/ll/n6/w2zxbe.jpg](http://screenshu.com/static/uploads/temporary/91/ll/n6/w2zxbe.jpg)

Comment: If at all then the browser would be ignoring something, css is just a passive language. But I don't see the point here. "inline" does not mean no line break may occur. A line will get wrapped if it is not wide enough to hold the content. Remember that when zooming you do _not_ also zoom the window size. So the window gets _smaller_ from a relative point of view. Therefore there is less space in the line.

Comment: that 2 objects are inside a div with "display: table; width: auto;"

Comment: Yes, so? Nevertheless what I wrote applies. The parent container shrinks in relative view, there is not enough room left, so the line must get wrapped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property you have assigned is not being ignored. That is the correct behaviour for display: inline. The reason this is happening is because upon zooming, the parent container is shrinking relative to its children and the child items do not have a constraint which disallows them to break to a new line. In order to continue being displayed without overflow, one of them displays itself on a new line.

In my opinion, the best option for achieving what you are trying to do is the flex box module. It is a module that was introduced with CSS3 and provides a solution for situations like this one. How to use the flex box module is explained very well here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/. The property you would need to apply to the children in the parent container is:

```
flex-wrap: nowrap;
```

This allows for the items to all be displayed on a single line.

This is, of course, not the only solution.

You could also set the parent container's minimum width to be greater than or equal to the sum of the widths of the children it is containing. Yet another option would be be to set the children's widths equal to a percent of their parent container. There are probably even more methods but again, flex box was designed for this sort of situation and offers a very clean and clear solution for not only this specific case, but for a vast number of display problems that have plagued web page styling in the past.

Comment: I added div with "width: auto; display table" inside old div now with "min-width: 1400px;" and that works! thx for help